# Compare 2nd column of two files and compute the percentage increase or decrease

Tags: python, list

I want to compare file1(numeric value after the comma) to file2(numeric value after the comma) and display percentage increase or decrease.

```
file1.csv
item1,100   
item2,150
item3,250
item4,550
item5,400
item6,125

file2.csv
item1,160
item2,180
item3,190
item4,1100
item5,100
item6,510

Result.csv
item1 +60%
item2 +20%
item3 -24%
item4 +100%
item5 -75%
item6 +308%
```

Comment: What have you tried? I would investigate using `pandas` for working with data like this.

Comment: I have not but I am still searching now. I have read about it though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into pandas for this one.

Something like this should work.

1. Read in both data sets
2. Merge them on the id column
3. Calculate the difference
4. Drop the columns we don't want anymore
5. Write the result to CSV

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header=None, names=['id', 'val_1'])
data2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header=None, names=['id', 'val_2'])

data1 \
    .merge(data2, on = 'id') \
    .assign(result = lambda data: data.val_2/data.val_1 - 1) \
    .filter(['id', 'result']) \
    .to_csv('Result.csv', header=None, index = False)
```

Comment: If having the % sign at the end of the result is important let me know and I can modify the code. I generally don't like casting numbers to strings if I'm going to write them to files.

Comment: Thank you. How to print result in the screen line by line instead of writing it to result.csv directly? For example, what if I just want to write to result.csv the line with > than 3% increase?

Comment: You can just remove the last line of the code. If "\.to_csv('Result.csv', header=None, index = False)" is excluded from the code it should automatically print to the console. If not, try using `.head()`.